Print the string of text from the chosen position by PYTHON
I would like to print the text from a chosen position from any text. For example: ASWBUR4HC - I wanna print the text from the third letter.
For example: ASWBUR4HC - I wanna print the text from the third letter
Output is: WBUR4HC

Did you do any investigation on your own?  As a general rule, this site looks far more positively on those who have done their own research before asking.  print(string[2:]).

You can achieve this by using string slicing:
>>> text = "ASWBUR4HC"
>>> start_index = 2  # Starting index, 2 for the third letter (0-based index)
>>> substring = text[start_index:]  # Extract substring starting from the third letter to the end
>>> print(substring)
WBUR4HC


look in the documentation here is the link and an example:
https://docs.python.org/3.12/tutorial/introduction.html
https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/brackets/slicing.html
# positive indexes [012345678]
text = 'Python s2'
print(text[8])

# negative indexes -[987654321]
print(text[-9])

# accessing slices
new_text = text[7:9]
print(new_text)

# skipping indices
new_text = text[0::3]
print(new_text)

# letter by letter
for letter in text:
    print(letter)



def printP(text, position):
    return text[position - 1:]

input_text = "ASWBUR4HC"
chosen_position = 3
output_text = printP(input_text, chosen_position)
print("Output is:", output_text)

Hope this helps
